# Schedule SQL in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a simple task at hand but it actually feels like a mountain, been cracking my head for almost a week now.

I have a simple create table query that needs to be run at 6 AM , I use teradata. Is there a way to run this SQL in a automated way.

Comment: A simple Google search turned up documentation on the Teradata Query Scheduler:  http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_13_10/index.html#page/Storage_Management/B035_2512_020A/2512ch04.06.2.html.

Comment: Thats a tool for DBA's not something that can used by a end SQL user.

Comment: Then set up a cron job on your local computer.  The point is, you need a job schedule to schedule a job.

Comment: Have to agree with Gordon here. You need a job scheduler either on your local computer or a server within your environment (e.g. BI server, UNIX Server, SAS Server, etc.) that will allow you to submit your job.

Comment: How can we do it in crontab? Kindly requesting if you can provide an example where we need username and pwd to login. Thank you.